# Vue.js 3 telepone field with country code input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Anyone know a way to insert a telephone field with a country code dropdown similar to the one in the link for vue3?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tel-input

I had tried to use the package in the link but it throws the following error in console.

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: selfHook.bind is not a function`

attempted implementation:

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import VueTelInput from 'vue-tel-input'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(VueTelInput)
app.mount('#app');
```

in the App.vue I just imported it like a component using the following code:

```
<vue-tel-input></vue-tel-input>
```

Comment: Can you try to call `use` after `mount`?

Comment: same error is prompted in console

Comment: That package [depends on Vue 2](https://github.com/EducationLink/vue-tel-input/blob/f476313/package.json#L60), so it won't work in a Vue 3 app. I recommend asking the maintainers to migrate to Vue 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted on an [open issue](https://github.com/EducationLink/vue-tel-input/issues/229) regarding Vue3 support for the library that they have created a Vue3 version of it: https://github.com/victorybiz/vue3-tel-input

I have tried it and it seems to work fine!

Answer (score 0):

This library supports Vue 3 now. https://vue-tel-input.iamstevendao.com/

`npm install vue-tel-input@next`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import VueTelInput from 'vue-tel-input';
import 'vue-tel-input/dist/vue-tel-input.css';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(VueTelInput);
app.mount('#app');
```

...

```
<template>
  <vue-tel-input v-model="phone"></vue-tel-input>
></template>
```

Comment: could u pls suggest the way to change the placeholder

Comment: Unfortunately no. I would recommend browsing the node_modules directory for the library and look at the component's code. You might be able to see how to add a placeholder.